# Regex Date Format?

Tags: regex

I do not know regex at all and I need to write a regex code that will validate date in this format:

`dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss`

code I tried: `[0-3][0-9].[0-1][0-9].[0-9][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]`

However when I tried sample data such as: `05.02.2009 15:26:39` it doesn't work.  I don't understand what I am doing wrong.  Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at the many examples given by Google ?

Comment: `.` matches any character, I think you want the literal `\.`.  Then `\s` to match space.

Comment: a regex is not enough to properly validate a date/time

Comment: [0-9][0-9] in the first half should match 2 digits, not 4. Also, the dot comment.

Comment: Your year portion only matches 2 digits, not 4.

Comment: What language? You'd be better off using a date/time library if the language has one.

Comment: What language are you using? A lot of times it's better to use a real parser than using a regexp.

Comment: **Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values.** Find a likely string with the regex, then check its numeric value in whatever your host language is (PHP, whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is for your year (yyyy) you are doing this: `[0-9][0-9]`, perhaps you want 4 numbers? `[0-9]{4}`

You should also escape your dots, otherwise they will match everything (including dots though)

```
[0-3][0-9]\.[0-1][0-9]\.[0-9]{4} [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

Works with your sample input:

http://www.debuggex.com/r/wjCqVufPzoQnqsm0

Comment: Np, btw this is a really strict regex. Depending on how you are using it, you might want to make it more flexible. Even just things like `[0-3]?[0-9]` for your day and `[./-]` in place of your `\.` could help if you are okay with a little flexibility to allow for things like "8/10/2009 14:45:12"

Comment: no, has to be dot.  I am not validating for date, I am validating for a string that has that format, and I changed the values to get the format that I need, now it works in the validators that I used to test it. its a complicated project to explain so I figured this question would get me the answer that I need without having to go too much in debt about the project, anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hardly to validate a date with just a regex. First, you need to escape every `.` of your regex, since it's a metacharacter. Year pattern is also wrong:

```
[0-3][0-9]\.[0-1][0-9]\.[0-9]{4} [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```